# What different video formats RTMP streaming support?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, flv

In almost all the online references related to FFMPEG and RTMP, I am getting **-f** as **flv**. Is there any other formats.

(I have tried **avi**, **mpeg** and **h264**, but no success.)

Currently, I am running following command -

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.mp4 -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -i audio.wav -c copy -f flv rtmp://192.168.0.1:1935/myapp/stream
```

The issues with -f flv in my case are -

- It doesn't support 48k sample rate.
- None of my input videos are in flv format (I have to convert it to flv externally).

P.S. - I am using VLC as RTMP player.

EDIT -

I am getting following error with 48k audio file -

> [flv @ 0x5650ba7afb80] FLV does not support sample rate 48000, choose from (44100, 22050, 11025)

Comment: Only FLV. Both RTMP and FLV are Adobe technologies. 48 kHz MP3 can be streamed with FLV.

Comment: @GyanThanks for info. I have added the error I am getting with 48K

Comment: Go with `ffmpeg -re -i video.mp4 -re  -i audio.wav -c:v copy -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://192.168.0.1:1935/myapp/stream`